# Gradient works for one photo but not others

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-image

I am trying to follow the Image Analysis with Scipy guide and mess around with things but a lot of it doesn't work when I change the image. for example,

```
import skdemo
from skimage import data
# Rename module so we don't shadow the builtin function
import skimage.filter as filters

image = data.camera()
pixelated = image[::10, ::10]
gradient = filters.sobel(pixelated)
skdemo.imshow_all(pixelated, gradient)
```

When I run this it works, but when I use `data.coffee()` or `data.chelsea()` I get a ton of errors. This also happens whenever I use the `convolve` function. Any idea why?

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-148-2dc2336cd0ef> in <module>()
  6 image = data.coffee()
  7 pixelated = image[::10, ::10]
----> 8 gradient = filters.sobel(pixelated)
  9 skdemo.imshow_all(pixelated, gradient)

/Users/(me)/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/filter/edges.pyc in sobel(image, mask)
 81     has to be further processed to perform edge detection.
 82     """
---> 83     return np.sqrt(hsobel(image, mask)**2 + vsobel(image, mask)**2)
 84 
 85 

/Users/(me)/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/filter/edges.pyc in hsobel(image, mask)
112     """
113     image = img_as_float(image)
--> 114     result = np.abs(convolve(image, HSOBEL_WEIGHTS))
115     return _mask_filter_result(result, mask)
116 

/Users/(me)/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/ndimage/filters.pyc in convolve(input, weights, output, mode, cval, origin)
693     """
694     return _correlate_or_convolve(input, weights, output, mode, cval,
--> 695                                   origin, True)
696 
697 

/Users/(me)/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/ndimage/filters.pyc in _correlate_or_convolve(input, weights, output, mode, cval, origin, convolution)
527     wshape = [ii for ii in weights.shape if ii > 0]
528     if len(wshape) != input.ndim:
--> 529         raise RuntimeError('filter weights array has incorrect shape.')
530     if convolution:
531         weights = weights[tuple([slice(None, None, -1)] * weights.ndim)]

RuntimeError: filter weights array has incorrect shape.
```

Comment: could you post the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sobel` expects a two-dimensional array.  The arrays returned by `skimage.data.coffee()` and `skimage.data.chelsea()` are three-dimensional, with shape (m, n, 3).  They represent color images, with red, green and blue channels.

To use one of them with the demo code, you could select one of the channels.  For example, the following works:

```
image = data.coffee()
pixelated = image[::10, ::10, 0]  # Use the red channel.
gradient = filters.sobel(pixelated)
```